# onClick function for the specific item in a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have objects stored in my state (workitems) with different attributes such as id, title, description etc. I map them out in my render in a table to make them visible. So far so good. But when I try to ad a "onClick" inside of the map function, it will not only trigger for the specific element that was clicked on, but all workitems object in the map will trigger as well.

In my render;

```
{workitem.company ? workitem.company + " - " : ""}

      <a href={workitem.url} target="_blank">{workitem.title}</a>
      <div className="description pt-2" onClick=  {this.descriptionPopOut(workitem.description)>  // My onclick function                            
           <strong>Description: </strong>                                         
           {workitem.description ? this.trimWord(workitem.description.replace("...", ""), 850, "...")
                                  : ""}{" "}
                                  ...
      </div>
```

The onClick will lead to a very simple function that has an alert, and take the object description as input.

```
descriptionPopOut = (description) => {
   alert(description); 
}
```

Above will make the alert pop out with all the object description property, and not for the specific element that has been clicked. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because on each render your function is calling i.e

```
this.descriptionPopOut(workitem.description)
```

. While you want to call on when you click. You can either bind the function so that you can use it later when you click :

```
this.descriptionPopOut.bind(this, workitem.description)
```

or you can use fat arrow function to return function i.e

```
onClick = {() => this.descriptionPopOut(workitem.description)>
```

(It ensure it creates function reference and when you click it, it invokes your function with specific param)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling function in each iteration.

Try doing like this:

```
this.descriptionPopOut.bind(this, workitem.description)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling your function incorrectly.

Don't do this `onClick = {this.descriptionPopOut(workitem.description)>`

Since you want to pass a parameter do this

`onClick = {() => this.descriptionPopOut(workitem.description)>`